# Calculate the mid-60% range

Tags: self-study, quantiles, range

I need some help please! I am not too sure how to answer question 1.3 regarding the "mid-60& range".

Are they looking for 60th percentile?

Thanks for the assistance!

[image]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the 60% interquantile range, i.e. the range between the 20th percentile and the 80th percentile:

IQR(60%) = 80th percentile - 20th percentile

The interquantile range (IQR) is a measure of statistical dispersion, being equal to the difference between the upper and lower quantiles, in your case the 80th percentile and the 20th percentile (80 - 20 = 60).

Comment: Thanks Stochazesthai. I am new to stats and would appreciate if you could provide me with a step by step solution in how to work this out. I am not certain how you you derived the 80th and 20th percentile. Please assist! Thanks

Comment: You are asked to write the mid-60% range, i.e. the dispersion in the middle 60% of the distribution. To consider the middle 60%, you have to "rule out" the 20% at the extremes of your distribution. Hence, by computing the difference between the 80th percentile and the 20th percentile, you can find the middle 60% range of you distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes alot of sense now! Thanks for the help- i really appreciate it!

Comment: The spirit here is right but the letter is wrong, or the ideas are explained awkwardly. The quartiles can **only** be defined as 25% and 75% quantiles or percentiles. As in the answer, the terms _quantile_ and also _percentile_ are available and totally preferable for values corresponding to other percent points. So the difference concerned could be called an interqua**n**tile range, although it is, I suggest,  more clearly explained as just a difference between particular percentiles or quantiles. The risk not spotting the difference between interquartile and interquantile is far too high.

Comment: Agree. Fixed it.